# Validation give me not correct result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wrote validation which check if `role` `admin` only one, `role` doesn't update on `user`. It's work, but then I have only  one `admin` I can't update another `users` to `admin`. Wrote validation exception.

I try write math operators, like `<=` and `<=>` but it not working. I need what I can update `user` to `admin` if I have only one `admin`.

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: %i[user admin]
  validate :admin_role

  private
  def admin_role
    errors.add(:role, 'Must be one admin') if Account.where(role: :admin).count == 1
  end
end
```

**accounts_controller**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @accounts = Account.all.order(:id)
    end

    def update
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
      if @account.valid? 
        @account.update(role: params[:role])
      else
        flash[:danger] = @account.errors.full_messages
      end
      redirect_to accounts_path
    end
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role", default: 0
end
```

Comment: If you have only 1 admin, you must be able to update a user to admin so there can be only 2 admins am I right?

Comment: @Hackman Partially. I want the ability to do more than one administrator on a list. The fact is that when I have one administrator, validation prevents me from creating a second one.

Comment: So what is it that you want to validate? Do you want to validate that there will always be 1 admin, so the last admin can't be updated to user? Or do you want to validate that only a admin can update users to admin? Or both.... ?

Comment: @Hackman both options.

Comment: For the first part you need to change your validation to check if count >= 1 (it needs to be bigger then or equal to 1). If there are no accounts yet, you can skip validation to create a first account. For the second validation, I have no idea how to check how is updating the user in the model. I do know how to fix that with a custom update action.

Comment: @Hackman The second option you can simply register yourself through the console. Do hardcore. Not all the same to please the customer. I’ll definitely try the first option. Thank you very much.